# netbooting CentOS via PXE and UEFI : unable to mount root over nfs -- failed to switch root path /sysroot

Tags: centos, nfs, pxe-boot, uefi, netboot

Last weekend, I went down the rabbit hole of trying to netboot rockylinux on raspberry pi 4.

I was able make it work as far as being able to boot the kernel. But I fail to properly nfs mount root. I get the error:
Failed to switch root path  /sysroot ... does not seem to on os-tree. os-release file missing.

My NFS server is rockylinux VM. I have disabled the firewall and made the root filesystem
read/write for all for debugging.
I am able to mount the nfs shares from other machines as well.   So I think the nfs exports are working properly.

Here is my grub menuentry:

```
set default="0"
set timeout=5
set root=(tftp,192.168.0.185)
set prefix=($root)/grub2

menuentry "OS (UEFI PXE)" {
    linux /vmlinuz-5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.aarch64 root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.0.185:/nfs/rpi4_dfd9 rw ip=dhcp rootwait elevator=deadline
    initrd /initramfs-5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.aarch64.img
}
```

How can I test nfs mount from recovery shell that kernel drops into after failing to properly mount the nfs drive?

Answer (score 1):

The rockylinux team pointed in the right direction. For pxeboot, one needs to use  pxeboot/vmlinux and pxeboot/initrd.img files found on the ISO's or dl.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/9/BaseOS.